# Getting different values from two different condition in a single query

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I need to have a result like below

```
section_one | section_two
56788              678
```

and this is the query I wrote to have the above result separately

```
Select count(*) as section_one from tableNew
WHERE columnone LIKE %hjk%
```

And

```
Select count(*) as section_two from tableNew
WHERE columnone NOT LIKE %hjk%;
```

How can I combine these two in one query and have the result as above?

I tried something below, but doesn't seem to work correctly

```
select *,
CASE
WHEN columnone LIKE %hjk% THEN count(1) as section_one
ELSE count(1) as section_two
END
from tableNew
Group by tableid;
```

Is there any other way as well to  have both the condition in one query instead?
Any help on this would be great!

**P.S:** Also is there any other way as well to check the `boolean` condition like instead of `columnone LIKE %hjk%` targeting `columnone IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `SUM`

```
select 
SUM(columnone LIKE %hjk%)  as section_one,
SUM(columnone NOT LIKE %hjk%)  as section_two
from tableNew
Group by tableid;
```

Or you you can use `CASE`

```
select 
SUM(CASE WHEN columnone LIKE %hjk% THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as section_one,
SUM(CASE WHEN columnone NOT LIKE %hjk% THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as section_two
from tableNew
Group by tableid;
```

Comment: Thank you M khalid Junaid, instead of `SUM` can i also use count? and for the `CASE` does it needs to go to the section to get it true to execute?

Comment: @akiiddweeber yes you can use `CASE` in `count` as well

Comment: `SUM` of a boolean won't work in PostgreSQL. The second will, and can be simplified to a `count` over a `CASE` with no `ELSE` clause (thus producing the default of `null`).

Comment: @Craig Ringer- So, if I have a condition like say ` SUM(columnone IS NULL) as section_one` would not work because it returns Boolean? so can I use `Count` instead to achieve that if I am focusing on such conditions? please correct me if I am missing any point.

Comment: @akiiddweeber if you use `SUM(columnone IS NULL)` will return boolean as true if null and evaluated as 1 in mysql/sql so in other word SUM will act like count if condition used in SUM()

Comment: Thank you M khalid Junaid, and how about in PostgreSQL? So for conditions like `IS NULL OR IS NOT NULL` in POSTGRESQL, it is better to pick the second case that you have provided instead of SUM and replace it with COUNT correct?

Comment: @akiiddweeber i am not familiar with postgresql so i can't tell you abot that and for the count you can use the case also

Comment: Thank you! Is there any other way to optimize this query since, I have millions of data and its taking very long to display any of the result if combined? (Just curious)

Comment: @akiiddweeber i guess adding a normal index for the `columnone` will be enough for this and select only the needed columns instead of selecting all columns

Comment: Great! Thank you once again. The second query using CASE and replacement of SUM with COUNT worked for me, the first query was giving the same count if replaced with count. Guess in postgresql it doesn't work well in boolean cases.